# How can I update my WinForm label on timer?

Tags: winforms, label

I can't update my WinForm label properties.

Details: I am trying to check my database and get some values posted, but I can't even update a mere label it seems. I'm using SharpDevelop.

The code:

```
//this is my form

public partial class MainForm : Form
{   

//Declaring timer
public static System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();

public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //Timer
    aTimer.Elapsed +=new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
    aTimer.Interval = 2000; //milisecunde
    aTimer.Enabled = true;  

    label1.Text="some_text";        
}

private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e) {Check();}

public static void Check()
{
    //Database checks here..

    try{label1.Text="new_text";}catch(Exception e)  {MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());}
    MessageBox.Show("BAAAA");
}

    void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "mergeeeeee?!";
    }

}
```

EDIT: I've removed all static modifiers. Also updated the post with the new code (try catch is added and the messagebox after it + a button that changes the label).
The try catches the following error:

[image]

. Really could use some help, been researching answers for more than 6 hours.

Comment: Start by removing all the `static` modifiers from your label, the timer, the event handler, and your `Check()` method. I suspect you really don't need all those things to be static.  Besides the use of static, the rest of your code looks fine.

Comment: Got rid off all static, seems it can run compile without them.. But no changes to label. Also I think my timer broke.. I tried adding MessageBox.Show("text") in the Check function and it won't appear

Comment: Add a button to your form and in it's clicked event handler, set the label1.Text to verify that you can change the text of the label. Also, try setting breakpoints in your `OnTimedEvent` handler, which is a better way to see if it is being called.

Comment: I've added the button and it changes the text of the label. Also it seems that all commands after label1.Text(in the Check function) are nulled. I've put try{}catch{} there and now I can call MessageBox after it. I think at that point( label1.text in check function) the program breaks.

Comment: There is something wrong with your label1. Your try/catch is eating the exception; you should display the exception in a message box in your `catch` block. I'm still not convinced you've removed all your `static` modifiers.  Finally, I would just create a brand new WinForm project, drag in a label, drag in timer and set a click handler and then write the line to change the label's text. No extra business with static methods and variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this (use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` instead of `System.Timers.Timer`):

```
//Declaring timer
public System.Windows.Forms.Timer aTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //Timer
    aTimer.Tick += aTimer_Tick;
    aTimer.Interval = 2000; //milisecunde
    aTimer.Enabled = true;

    label1.Text = "some_text";    
}

void aTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Check();
}

public void Check()
{            
    try 
    {
        //Database checks here..
        label1.Text = string.Format("new_text {0}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()); 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    MessageBox.Show("BAAAA");
}
```

The [Elapsed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event of the `System.Timers.Timer` is fired on a non-UI thread (change your original code to not swallow exceptions and you should see the cross-thread exception).

Comment: Seems to work. I'm really amazed.. so it was just the type of timer?

Comment: Well, not exactly.  The issue is that you were trying to modify a UI component from a thread that wasn't the same thread it was created on.  You could have used the System.Timers.Timer, but you would need to use Invoke/BeginInvoke on the UI Component(s) you wanted to modify.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code for my project and it worked.
It has a button to activate the timer and the timer raises an event when 500 milliseconds passed.

```
private void ActiveTimer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EnableTimer();
}

private void EnableTimer()
{
    System.Timers.Timer raiseTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    raiseTimer.Interval = 500;
    raiseTimer.Elapsed += RaiseTimerEvent;
    raiseTimer.AutoReset = true;
    raiseTimer.Enabled = true;
}

private void RaiseTimerEvent(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Invoke(new Action(() => 
        {
            label1.Text += "500 ms passed\n";
        }));
}
```